# Loop with InputBox until a unique reference is written

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a loop. I'm beginnning with it and I cannot make it work correctly.

I have a macro that create an inputbox to obtain a unique reference. Then, the macro is checking is the reference is already used in a range. If yes, it says where and asked the user to use another reference.

I tried few different code but cannot make it worked well. It does continues even if the reference is not unique or it loop again and again even if the reference is unique... I think I did not place my code where it should be.

Can you please help me solve this ?

```
    Set Rng = Range("A1:A100")
reference = InputBox("What is the reference  ? (Example : UN.2019.04.31)", "Reference required")
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = reference
SearchString = reference

For Each aCell In Rng
    If InStr(1, aCell.Value, SearchString, vbTextCompare) Then
        MsgBox "This reference is already used at line " & aCell.Address
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "REFERENCE ALREADY USED"
    End If
Next
reference = InputBox("Please chose another reference.", "Reference")

Do Until Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Value <> "REFERENCE ALREADY USED"
    For Each aCell In Rng
        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, SearchString, vbTextCompare) Then
            MsgBox "This reference is already used at line " & aCell.Address
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "REFERENCE ALREADY USED"
            reference = InputBox("Please chose another reference.", "Reférence")
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = reference
        End If

    Next
Loop
```

PS : why I cannot say hello before posting ? (Each time I edit, it deletes itself the word)

Comment: It is against the policy to say `Hello`  Just give the question and back up information.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Exit For when the condition is met. For example, here is how the top for loop should be.

```
For Each aCell In Rng
    If InStr(1, aCell.Value, SearchString, vbTextCompare) Then
        MsgBox "This reference is already used at line " & aCell.Address
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "REFERENCE ALREADY USED"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```